# Quadratic Function one to one

Tags: functions

If a function takes one value from domain and gives a unique value in range it is one to one. But if that is the case, why are quadratic functions considered as functions? like $x^2$ gives the output $1$ when $x= 1$ and when $x= -1$. Does this mean $x^2$ is not a function?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Every* function maps a point of its domain into a single point of its range. We say that a function is one to one when no point of the range is the image of more than one point of its domain. So, $x\mapsto x^2$ is a function which is *not* one to one.

Comment: Then why do we call it a quadratic 'function'? Is it because we can think of it being divided into two parts like from the turning point?

Comment: We call it function because it is a function. I think that it's a good reason. What do you think?

Comment: ohh i get it now. Thank you so much for the clarification.

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: done. i am new here so appreciate the help